# Best Session Storage Middleware for Express + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I was looking for the best middleware for storing session data in MongoDB to use in a production application that uses express?

I've been looking around and found this:

1. **session-mongoose**
   (https://github.com/donpark/session-mongoose)
   According to author's comment this is not production-ready for following reasons:

   > - insufficient testing
   > - zero optimization
   > - there are better
   >     options than MongoDB for session storage
2. **connect-mongo** (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)
3. **express-session-mongo** (https://github.com/davglass/express-session-mongo)

   > Based on these classes
   >
   > - Sencha Connect Memory Store
   > - ciaranj's express-session-mongodb
4. **connect-session-mongo** (https://github.com/bartt/connect-session-mongo)

I've been looking at their code, I was trying to find also a performance comparisson article. Do you guys have experience to suggest which is the best?

Comment: Unless you are doing something really fancy with sessions you should just use cookie sessions. I am saying this because 99% of the time people are using sessions to store a user ID. Sessions work by matching a session ID inside a cookie to an ID in that database. So if you use it for a user ID you are actually storing an ID (session) inside a cookie to match with an ID (session) in the database to return an ID (user). While you could just store the user ID inside the cookie right away.

Comment: If you stored a user id in the cookie, the user would be able to spoof that id and impersonate another user.  Sessions are more secure and database backed session stores ensure that your application will work across load balancers.

Comment: @Abadaba That's where the obfuscation/cryptography is helpful. You should never output real, pattern-identifiable values from your DB to the Client in relation to user/account information.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**connect-mongo** (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) looks better then others.

**express-session-mongo** and **connect-session-mongo** are very old and based on old version of `mongodb` driver.

**session-mongoose** based on `mongoose`, that slower than `mongodb` driver.

I think **connect-mongo** is the best choose.

Answer (score 3):

---

**connect-mongodb-session**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongodb-session
- Published 3 months ago
- **connect-mongodb-session**: *MongoDB-backed session storage for connect and Express. Meant to be a well-maintained and fully-featured replacement for modules like **connect-mongo***
- Google also now shows this one first.

---

**connect-mongo**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo
- Published a year ago

---

Comment: Now these both packages are seems to be updated ones. I am using connect-mongo as I had referred one project for that. But in case of mongodb is not available it is failing. Is there any mechanism to retry in connect-mongo? I have posted question below, but unable to find any solution so far.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410326/connect-mongo-auto-reconnect