# Keep passport session alive during server restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Is there a way that I can maintain the user session over a server restart to help keep my development nice and fast?

I'm working on an ExpressJS node project locally on my machine. I'm using [Grunt-nodemon](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon) to watch my JS files and restart the server once i've made changes. What this means though is that any sessions on my project (there's a user log in) are wiped clean.

Currently if I'm in a deep page somewhere and restart, I'm kicked out to the log-in page and have to re-navigate which is really frustrating.

I'm using passport as the session middleware. I'm using mongoose as my main application datastore, if I can use that somehow that would be super.

Comment: Use some other storage for your sessions like redis instead of memory store which is default. But unless you are doing something very fancy with sessions, I will recommened using cookie based sessions.

Comment: The sessions are cookie-based still, it's just that they're not valid after the server restarts. Isn't redis a database solution?

Comment: Here is a mongodb solution: [Node.js + express.js + passport.js : stay authenticated between server restart](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10164312/)

Comment: You must not use MemoryStore, also, make sure that the sessionSecret you are using is not changing between server restarts (I had this problem); if sessionSecret is changing express wont be able to recover your data from database/chosen sessionStore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very possible with the simple usage of any storage method.

One option is to use Redis.

Here is example that uses the `connect-redis` module:

```
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    var session = require('express-session');
    var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
    app.use(express.session(
        {
            store: new RedisStore(
                {
                    host: '127.0.0.1',       //where redis store is
                    port: 6379,              //default redis port
                    prefix: 'sess',          //prefix for sessions name is store
                    pass: 'passwordtoredis'  //password to redis db
                }
            ),
            secret: 'cookiesecret',        //cookie secret
            key: 'express.sid'
        }

));
```

It could be more concisely, but it should work well.

Setting up redis is quite easy; the redis webpage has a great tutorial for that: http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

Please remember that redis by default stores the session in memory, which means that if you restart your hardware, the session will be lost (but there is an option to make it persist http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you reckon I could use my current mongoose setup to store the session?

Comment: Yes. And there are utilities for that purpose (similar to redis connect) that do that and as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059051/best-session-storage-middleware-for-express-mongodb states, connect-mongo looks like best package for that purpose. here is the link: https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo . Of course You can use mongoose explicitly and write Your own store :).

Comment: Brilliant. I upgraded to Express 4.x and used connect-mongo. Works perfectly and is saving me so much time. Thanks again, keep it up :)