# Connect-mongo Alternative for Express 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I am looking to implement cookiestore in my Express app, I followed this question

> [Best Session Storage Middleware for Express + MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059051/best-session-storage-middleware-for-express-mongodb)

and

> https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo

for my Express 3.x project, but for Express 4, `connect` middleware is deprecated.

Which is the suitable alternative for connect-mongo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Middleware has been extracted out of the core and moved individual modules.  This changes how you set up the app but you have the option to use the same middleware as before.  The [overview](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#overview) explaining how to migrate from 3.x to 4.x lists the modules that can be used as replacements for the Connect middleware.

The syntax will be *slightly* different as you explicitly install the modules, such as `express-session`, and the `app.use` statements are modified to reflect this.  The options you pass to these modules, however, are the same as it was with the Connect middleware...so you can pass your `connect-mongo` details to `express-session` and keep rolling along.

So you don't have to change unless there's another problem that isn't clear in your original question...and there could be other problems if you have a large, established app. But if you are following a tutorial, you should be early enough in the process that this won't be a major issue.

**Edit**: It looks like there's also been [discussion about Express 4](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/109#issuecomment-40551208) on the `connect-mongo` github page.  There are more examples there about how to use this module with the new version of Express...

**Edit 2**: The code, referenced a few times on the github page, looks like this:

```
var session    = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'youshouldputyourownsecrethere',
    store: new MongoStore({
        db              : mongoose.connection.db,
    })
}));
```

Comment: i replace this code from documentation `var session = require('express-session'), RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session); app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore(options), secret: 'keyboard cat' }))`
with `var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);` and I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined

Comment: The fix is (as of 15 minutes ago when he published the fix to NPM) is: **switch to [connect-mongostore](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-mongostore)**. Their team is picking up more momentum for [Express 4.0 support](https://github.com/diversario/connect-mongostore/pull/8).

Comment: That's an option but it looks like the syntax in my second edit works until the author makes updates to make the `(session)` parameter unnecessary.  So it looks more like 'which option is most suitable' than one or the other being strictly correct.