# How to get a connection to mongoDB to use the express session?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Previously I follow a YouTube tutorial to make a node-express app without session, I am now trying to include session into this app. But I cannot figure out what to put in the MongoStore.create()

index.js

```
const connectDB = require("./db/connect");
const authenticateUser = require("./middleware/authentication");
// routers
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("jobs api");
});
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/jobs", authenticateUser, jobsRouter);

//const sessionStore = MongoStore.create({});

// app.use(
//   session({
//     secret: "some secret",
//     resave: false,
//     saveUninitialized: true,
//     store: sessionStore,
//     cookie: {
//       maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, 
//     },
//   })
// );
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

connect.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = (url) => {
  return mongoose.set("strictQuery", true).connect(url);
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

I have tried something like conn = mongoose.connection.getClient() in the connect.js and export it to index.js as well, but the MongoStore.create({conn}) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14060310/16251783

connect-mongo (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) looks better then others.

express-session-mongo and connect-session-mongo are very old and based on old version of mongodb driver.

session-mongoose based on mongoose, that slower than mongodb driver.

I think connect-mongo is the best choose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).